# Play framework Windows v's Linux file path

Tags: java, linux, playframework

I have developed a Play framework application on my windows PC and then transferred it onto my Linux box, I'm uploading a video and a photo to the server, this upload process works perfectly on my Windows PC, but doesn't work on the Linux box.

code I'm using in windows:

```
        String root = Play.application().path().toString();
        String globalFolderPath = root + "/public/globalUploadFolder/";
        File globalFolder = new File(globalFolderPath);
```

Code I tried in Linux as well as the above code:

```
            String globalFolderPath = "../../public/globalUploadFolder/";
            File globalFolder = new File(globalFolderPath);
```

Is there a something I have to do regarding file paths differently on the Linux box, could it be a permission issue?

I'm lost as to why this is happening.

Comment: Is about separator that you use in globalFolderPath variable. Try to use File.separator.

Comment: is there any error or exception?

Comment: @user1929959 File.separator didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Diego no error or exception

Comment: Ok, what `doesn't work` mean then? Also, about the code you post, how is that related to the problem? How are the `File` objects used? I think you need to provide more information for others to be able to help

Comment: @user1929959 File.separator actually did work, thank you, if you want to answer the question I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Johntk Are you running both in the same mode (dev/prod)? Make sure that path exists (you can log the value of `globalFolderPath` in the first code part) and check if that folder can be accessed by the user you run Play with (you can use `ls -la /value/of/globalFolderPath`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using `File.separator`